# Trying to connect from Jenkins to Cygwin sshd randomly does not work (could not write ident string to [clientIP]

Tags: jenkins, ssh, tcp, cygwin, openssh

I'm trying to connect from Jenkins (docker container) to a windows server (VM) running a Cygwin sshd. The problem I'm facing is that (seemingly) at random I can or cannot connect. This is both with the 'SSH Plugin' (username/password) and via shell SSH command (key pair).

From Jenkins the debug information tells me:

```
debug1: connect to address [serverIP] port 22: Connection refused
```

When it **isn't** working the sshd log tells me:

```
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Forked child 1128.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 7 config len 232
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 6 sock 7
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from [clientIP] port 59440 on 0.0.0.0 port 22
Could not write ident string to [clientIP] port 59440
```

When it **is** working I get the following in the sshd log:

```
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Forked child 1708.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 7 config len 232
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 6 sock 7
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from [clientIP] port 56742 on [serverIP] port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.4
```

Difference I'm seeing is the 0.0.0.0 instead of the serverIP but I cannot find why this is.

I've tried setting up a job that runs every 5 minutes to see if there was a pattern, but I could find none.

On the server I've made a wireshark trace these are the packages I get

```
Client to server: [SYN]
Client to server: [TCP Out-Of-Order] (same package as previous [SYN])
Server to client: [RST, ACK]
Client to server: [SYN, ACK]
Client to server: [TCP Retransmission] (same package as previous [SYN, ACK])
```

I'm a bit stumped on the "Could not write ident string to [clientIP]" message and I'm having some trouble finding more information about why this is happening.
Any help on troubleshooting this further or information on why this message is displayed is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" normally means the server isn't accepting connections to the IP address and port that you requested. The service that you're trying to connect to may not be listening for connections, or it may be listening to a different address and/or port.

"Connection refused" can also be caused by a firewall blocking connections. In your case, given that the service is logging an incoming connection but without the client IP address, my guess is that you have some kind of firewall or malware detection software running on the server, and it's interfering with these connection attempts.

You'll need to access this firewall software, figure out why it's blocking these connections, and configure it to stop interfering.